# Issue with phantom popup using Colorbox in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, popup, colorbox

I've not been able to figure out why I get this appearing/disappearing popup when clicking on links on this page http://www.usalight.com/light-bulbs-s/1513.htm that aren't referencing the colorbox script.

If you click, for example, the halogen bulbs section, you'll see a colorbox popup appear and quickly disappear.  I'm only using colorbox for the horizontal "Light Bulbs" banner where it says, "What Color Temperature do you need?"

I'm only getting this behavior in IE8.  Every other browser I've tried works fine, including IE9.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason unrelated to colorbox, the banner link is actually encompassing a large part of your document.  When you click on a link, say halogen bulbs, both that link and the banner link is being clicked.  You can see this more clearly by clicking between the thumbnails rather than on them.

Comment: Yeah, I have the whole banner as an <a> link.  It's when I click below that on any of the grid thumbnails (Halogen Bulbs, LED Bulbs, etc.) that I get this behavior described above in IE8.

Comment: That's what I was commenting on, clicking below the banner.  The link to the banner is taking up way more space than you think it is.  I imagine your markup or CSS is malformed in some way, and IE8 is resolving this in a different way than the other browsers.

Comment: I'm only seeing the height as 97px, and I have this line separating the banner from the thumbnails:
<div style="height:1px;width:100%;clear:both;"></div>  Is it possible to extend below that?